# Increase index of a form's input field's name attribute in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Suppose I have this form with indexed input fields `username` and `level`:

```
<form>
 <table>
  <tr class="trToClone">
    <td>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username[0]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Level:</label>
      <select name="level[0]">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" class="addField" value="Add" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>  
</form>
```

The row can be repeated using this jQuery:

```
$("input.addField").on('click', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('.trToClone');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
});
```

Now for every subsequent row I add, I want to increase the indices of the `name` attribute (i.e. `username[1]`,`level[1]`; `username[2]`,`level[2]`; and so on...). How can I do this? I've looked for possible solutions, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple buttons are just one at the end which will always add element to the end. Because currently you will have multiple buttons and they will not work correctly if you try to add element in between to buttons. As well clone with setting it parameters to true will not clone your click handler for the button.

Comment: One at the end, preferably. Didn't work in jsfiddle when I tried it like that, hence this way.

Comment: Then pull out the button out of that table row, maybe the best right after closing table tag and try the code that @wscourge has written. This way you don't have to worry about event bindings and you just replicate _static_ element with few changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE: changing name attributes dynamically.

you can use a counter for counting your clicks! You have to move the "add" click button out of the table row.
HTML:

```
<form>
 <input type="button" class="addField" value="Add" />
 <table>
  <tr class="trToClone">
    <td>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username[0]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Level:</label>
      <select name="level[0]">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 0;
$("input.addField").on('click', function() {
    counter++;
  var $tr = $('.trToClone:eq(0)');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  var newTextName = $clone.find(':text').attr('name').replace(/\[(\d)+\]/,'[+ counter +']');
  $clone.find(':text').attr('name',newTextName);
  $clone.find('.dropdown').attr('name','level['+ counter + ']');
  $tr.parent().append($clone);
});
```

check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gknrfw1g/2/

Comment: Cool! I'll try this out on my project and let you know.

Comment: This works fine for just one text input field. What if I have, say, "firstName" as another text field? Wouldn't `$clone.find(':text').attr('name','username['+ counter + ']');` change that field name to "username" as well?

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: I made a change to the answer! you have to use a regex to recognize the "[x]" in the name and change it through [y].

Answer (score 2):

Specify new index with `$('.trToClone').length`, modify it on each element with `name` attribute with jQuery `.attr()` method:

```js
$("input.addField").on('click', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('.trToClone');
  var $clone = $tr.clone(true, true);
  
  var $names = $clone.find('[name]');
  var trIndex = $('.trToClone').length;
  
  $names.each(function(index, element) {
     
    var newName = $(element).attr('name').replace(/[0-9]/g, trIndex);
   
    $(element).attr('name', newName);
    
    console.log($(element).attr('name'));
  
  });
  
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <table>
  <tr class="trToClone">
    <td>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username[0]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Level:</label>
      <select name="level[0]">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" class="addField" value="Add" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>  
</form>
```

Comment: I think he needs to clone element with its bindings as well. So if you want to clone your element and have button retain its click handler he should use .clone(true, true) as stated in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.addField').click(function(){
  var count = $('#btnIncrease').val();
  var $tr = $(this).closest('.trToClone');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  count++;
  $('#btnIncrease').val(count);
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $clone.find(':text').attr('name', 'username[' + count + ']');
  $tr.after($clone); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="trToClone">
    <td>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username[0]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Level:</label>
      <select name="level[0]">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" class="addField" value="Add" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 <input type="hidden" id="btnIncrease" value="0" />
```

This would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For adding the name attribute you first need to find the index of current row and then you can add 1 to the index and again update the name attribute for both text and select list. Try with the code below-

Note- You should also hide the add button from previous row and bind the click function again for the newly cloned row.

```js
 $("input.addField").on('click', function() {
      var $tr = $(this).closest('.trToClone');
      var $clone = $tr.clone();
      var lastIndexName= $clone.find(':text').attr("name").split('[');
      var lastIndex=parseInt(lastIndexName[1].substring(0,1));
      var updatedNameValue="username["+(lastIndex+1)+"]";
      $clone.find(':text').attr("name",updatedNameValue);
      $clone.find(':text').val('');
      $clone.find('select').attr("name","level["+(lastIndex+1)+"]")
      $tr.after($clone);
    });
```